# After mistakenly committed huge files, I did reset to HEAD^, but my .git folder is still huge. How can I shrink it (remove unwanted pack)?

Tags: git

Note: this issue does not involve .gitignore.

So I accidentally committed ~50MB of non-code files into git, then my `.git` folder grew from <1MB to ~50MB.

I then did `git reset --hard HEAD^`, then even continued to make 2 more regular commits after that. The wrong commit is now gone for good, and there's no other branch.

However, my `.git` folder is still ~50MB. I tried all kinds of different things to shrink it, for instance:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git gc
git gc --aggressive
git gc --prune=now
git prune
git prune --expire now
```

etc...

However, none of these worked, the `.git` folder is still ~50MB, and it really bothers me. I looked inside, the big file is located in `.git/objects/pack`, it's a single big `.pack` file of ~50MB. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *probably* should do is wait: the condition will clear itself up, though not for at least 30 days by default, and it may take months.

If the situation *really* bothers you, clone the clone, make sure the new clone has everything you want, and remove the original clone.  Or, use `git reflog` to expire the reflogs right away, then `git gc` with `--prune=now`.  The `git reflog expire` step is what you omitted in what you have done so far.  See [the `git filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) for additional details:

```sh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Note that this makes it impossible to undo certain operations, so be *very sure* before you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if [this config setting](https://gist.github.com/vraravam/eab090e70a545934f409#file-gitconfig-L110) works for you.

```sh
git config --global alias.st cc "!echo \"Size before: $(du -sh .git | cut -f1)\"; git remote prune origin; git repack; git prune-packed; git reflog expire --all --expire=1.week.ago; git gc --force --aggressive --prune=now; echo \"Size after: $(du -sh .git | cut -f1)\";"
```

The setting uses the `du` disk utility command in macos/bsd-unix to print the size of your git folder before and after the operation.

The actual operation is to invoke git with different commands like `prune`, `repack`, `prune-packed`, etc.

There are 2 switches taking timespan (one being `1.week.ago` and another `now` - which can both be customized as to your preference.

I have been using this git config setting for the past decade or so with good luck in keeping all my git repos taking as little space as possible on my machine while still retaining 1 week of orphaned data. Good luck!